# Regex to capture characters at set positions in a variable string

Tags: regex

I'm not even sure this is possible with Regular Expressions but here is the scenario: I have a string that can be either 2, 4, or 6 characters in length.  The characters are digits that are in pairs (example: 01 or 0125 or 012589).

I need three expressions that capture the first two digits ("01" in the above example), middle digits ("25"), and last two "89" (again, these are just examples and can be ANY digit between 0 and 9).

The expression must conform to the restricted character length of the string (must be 2, 4, or 6 characters - 1, 3, 5, 7 or more characters would not cause a match).  Also, the expression that captures the last two digits CANNOT match the last two digits of a 4 character string.  Last two digits are only valid for a 6 character string.  Similarly, the middle capture is only valid for a 4 or 6 character string.

I cannot use code for this, only a regular expression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this pattern:

```
(?<!\d)(?<first>[0-9]{2})(?:(?<middle>[0-9]{2})(?<last>[0-9]{2})?)?(?!\d)
```

Answer (score 3):

It seems much easier to do this without using regular expressions, but for the sake of argument, you can use this pattern:

```
^(\d\d)(\d\d)?(\d\d)?$
```

Or this pattern, which actually has only one capture group, which might be easier to work with depending on your code:

```
^(\d\d){1,3}$
```

Both patterns will match either 2, 4, or 6 digits in groups of two and nothing else. Test it out [here](http://rubular.com/r/UeBjDix8ZH).